# facebook login with apple TV and smartphone

Tags: facebook, device, tvos

I have implemented facebook login via https://facebook.com/device for apple TV (tvos) , it's working fine but if I try to type the code on a smartphone browser ( https://m.facebook.com/device ) , I get an error message saying my url is not authorized..

http://accessdev.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/ATV_Fb_device_login.png

I guess I have to add the m.facebook.com support somewhere ? or maybe it's there an issue on facebook side.

I have followed the steps here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices#tech-step-enable-login-for-devices , and activated login for devices in the app settings

http://accessdev.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/login_from_devices.PNG

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message? That screenshot is too low resolution to read.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the steps outlined on

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices#tech-step-enable-login-for-devices

especially that you need to change your app's settings via

> Settings > Advanced > OAuth Settings > Login from Devices

to `'Yes'`? I guess this could be the reason. Apart from that, have you enabled any platforms in the app's settings?

Comment: yes, the login is working from a desktop computer (performed from www.facebook.com) , but not working from m.facebook.com

Comment: That's not really answering my question I think... Have you set the option?

Comment: yes it is. the login won't work with login for devices disable. I mean it working when you type the code on http://www.facebook.com/device

Comment: about the platforms, yes we support ios & android